# Exception when using google_trans_new

Tags: python-3.x

I want to run this example from the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/google-trans-new/) of the package

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator  

detector = google_translator()  
detect_result = detector.detect('สวัสดีจีน')
```

But I got this exception
[image]

I also attached the line mentioned in the error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bug in the package, I just made the following change

```
response = (decoded_line + ']')
```

to

```
response = decoded_line
```

Note that my error was at line 340 not in line 151 like [this solution](https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new/issues/36).But still can be solved the same way.